# Errors after Angular 4 upgrade from Angular 2

Tags: typescript, npm, upgrade, angular

I get these errors in the CLI after upgrading from Angular2 to Angular4. Though my app is still working after the upgrade, I'm just wondering how or if these errors can be resolved. Any ideas?

[image: cli logs]

Package.json before upgrade :

```js
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Package.json after upgrade :

```js
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You upgraded *@angular* libraries, but you didn't upgrade required dependecies. I suggest you to use *npm-check-updates*. It's the simplest way to upgrade all dependencies in your package.json. Try this:

**Step 1.** To install *npm-check-updates*:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

---

**Step 2.** to upgrade all dependencies:

```
npm-check-updates -u
```

**@EDIT:** or for the latest version npm-check-updates:

```
ncu -a
```

---

**Step 3.** To install upgrading dependencies:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading your Compiler CLI to `^4.0.0`:

Your compiler is still at version 2.4.0:

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
```

NB: if you wanna know how your package.json should look like you can create a new project `ng new test-project --skip-install` and check the package.json.